# Why not using two articles?

Tags: articles

The can used when I repeat the same meaning or I use a superlative, so to use two meanings should I use two 'the'? the and the hotter boy or the the hotter boy

Comment: Look carefully at your model sentence. It needs correcting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't repeat articles like that in English. There's no point to asking why; if you do it, it's not English.
You could possibly say "The boy who is the hottest", but that's different.